# Limit involving branch point of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble with the following problem :
If we restrict ourselves to that branch of $f(z)= \sqrt{z^2+3}$   for which $f(0)=\sqrt 3$ , prove that $$\lim_ {z\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{z^2+3}-2}{z-1} = 1/2$$
I can do the usual algebra tricks that gets this answer. However I need :
1. An epsilon delta proof (because this problem appears in that section of my book)
2. I really need to know how the assumption $f(0)=\sqrt 3$ comes into play ...
Please help...

Answer (score 1):

The limit only makes sense if $\lim\limits_{z\to1}\sqrt{z^2+3}=2$. Then, if $|z-1|\le\frac12$, we have
$$
|z+1|\le\frac52\tag{1}
$$
$$
|z|\ge\frac12\tag{2}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sqrt{z^2+3}\right|
&=\left|\sqrt{(z-1)(z+1)+4}\right|\\
&\ge\sqrt{4-\frac12\cdot\frac52}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{11}}2\\
&\ge\frac32\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\sqrt{z^2+3}-2}{z-1}-\frac12\right|
&=\left|\frac{z+1}{\sqrt{z^2+3}+2}-\frac12\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{z-\frac12\sqrt{z^2+3}}{\sqrt{z^2+3}+2}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{\frac34(z^2-1)}{(\sqrt{z^2+3}+2)(z+\frac12\sqrt{z^2+3})}\right|\\
&\le\frac{\frac34\cdot\frac52}{(\frac32+2)(\frac12+\frac34)}|z-1|\\[6pt]
&=\frac37|z-1|\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hi, I still do not understand .....Is this an epsilon delta proof??